# python and threading- code after thread.start() not being ran -- code stops

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, localhost, subprocess

I am attempting to get this function to run:

```
def local_server():

    # Start local
    unix_python_bin = "py_env/bin/python"
    unix_script_file = "./run.py"

    win_python_bin = "win_py_env/Scripts/python"
    win_script_file = "./run.py"

    try:

        system = platform.system()
        if "windows" in system.lower():
            theproc = subprocess.Popen([win_python_bin, win_script_file])
            theproc.communicate()
        else:
            subprocess.Popen([unix_python_bin, unix_script_file])

        set_server_connected(True)

    except:

        set_server_connected(False)
```

as a thread because this process starts a localhost server and takes up the terminal causing the user to have to press Ctrl+C to close the localhost. I am wanting to get the localhost started in the background and keep it going as the python app will interact with it.

As of now I call that function with:

```
server = Thread(target = local_server)
server.start()
```

The call works and the localhost gets started but the code never gets to set_server_connected(). The terminal is also held up by the server waiting for Ctrl+C.

How can I make this code run without stopping?

Comment: `communicate()` will block until the sub-process ends. Is that what you want?

Comment: no, i want it to run the python script and while that script is running continue through the code and reach the `set_server_connected(True)` the `communicate()` is the windows os version of the command which does as you say, block until it ends and also the `subprocess.Popen` which is the unix verison of  the command does this too. i want both to run the script and not block until they end.

Comment: last night i was working on a mac and the Popen was also blocking. today i am on windows and i changed the windows code to a Popen call `subprocess.Popen([win_python_bin, win_script_file])` and the subprocess is still blocking (stuck waiting for process to end). am I using the subprocess.Popen() correctly? looking at the docs, it seems like i am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the docs on subprocess I got it working by adding:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
```

and changing:

```
    if "windows" in system.lower():
        theproc = subprocess.Popen([win_python_bin, win_script_file])
        theproc.communicate()
    else:
        subprocess.Popen([unix_python_bin, unix_script_file])

    set_server_connected(True)
```

to this:

```
   if "windows" in system.lower():
        p = Popen([win_python_bin, win_script_file], stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, shell = False)
   else:
        p = Popen([unix_python_bin, unix_script_file], stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, shell = False)
```